# NSNotificationCenter chama várias vezes a página - Swift

Tags: swift, iphone

Quero fazer o seguinte:

1º o utilizador está na app e decide sair. Carregando no botão home do iphone.

2º o utilizador entra na app e em vez de continuar na página onde estava quando saiu, a app envia o utilizador automáticamente para a página principal.

O que fiz foi o seguinte:

no método viewDidLoad coloquei

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willEnterForeground), name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
```

e no método coloquei

```
let mapViewControllerObejct = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainMenuIdentifier") as? MainMenu
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mapViewControllerObejct!, animated: true)
```

e coloquei este código em todas as ViewControllers, o problema é que quando chamo muitas ViewController, e depois saiu da app e volto a entrar a app faz tantas chamadas da página principal quantas ViewControllers tinha chamado antes da sair da app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está justamente em colocar esse código em todos os *view controllers*. Todos eles vão receber a notificação quando o dito evento ocorrer (mesmo que não sejam o "presente na tela" no momento da ação).

> Uma possível **primeira** solução é colocar esse código apenas no primeiro view controller (`rootViewController`) do `UINavigationController`, já que provavelmente ele nunca sai da memória (a não ser que você substitua o mesmo).

Não esqueça de remover os objetos do `NSNotificationCenter`, seja no `deinit` ou no `willMoveToParentViewController(nil)`, senão o objeto será retido na memória.

> Uma **segunda** solução é utilizar os métodos `applicationWillResignActive:` e `applicationWillEnterForeground:` do AppDelegate, que foram criados exatamente para lidar com situações desse tipo.

Para implementar essa opção, vai no `AppDelegate` e implementa a lógica dentro desses dois métodos, sendo o `applicationWillResignActive:` pra quando o app vai entrar em background e o `applicationWillEnterForeground:` para quando o app vai voltar pro foreground. O sistema chama esses métodos automagicamente (com o perdão da piada) quando os respectivos eventos acontecem.

Você consegue acesso aos seus *view controllers* através da variável `window`. O primeiro *view controller* da hierarquia está disponível em `self.window.rootViewController`.

O problema dessa solução é que você vai ter que ir totalmente contra os padrões de design de orientação a objetos e vai ter que forçar downcast, para poder acessar os métodos dos teus *view controllers*, dessa maneira:

```
let myVc = self.window!.rootViewController as! MyViewController
```

Vai funcionar, porém o código vai ficar acoplado, deselegante e vai dar um pouquinho de trabalho caso você queira alterar o tipo de *view controller*. É tua responsabilidade decidir se isso é ruim ou não para a tua aplicação.

Eu vi que você está utilizando um `UINavigationController`, certo?

> Uma **terceira** solução (a melhor e mais elegante, na minha humilde opinião) seria criar uma subclasse de `UINavigationController` e sobrescrever o construtor.

No novo construtor, a única adição seria registrar o proprio objeto no `NSNotificationCenter`para receber as notificações que você quer utilizar. Pra você ter uma ideia, seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willEnterForeground), name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
}

// implementar willEnterForeground e afins
```

Depois que fizer isso, basta ir na *storyboard* (caso esteja usando-a) e trocar a classe do `UINavigationController` para a tua classe nova. Caso esteja fazendo programaticamente, basta mudar a classe que está cendo instanciada.

**Dica**: Eu vi que, na tua implementação, você simplesmente "pusha" (ato de fazer *push*) o `mapViewControllerObject` na pilha de *view controllers* do *navigation controller*. Isso daí é bem problemático, por uma das dessas duas razões: Se for o mesmo objeto, vai dar erro, pois não somos autorizados a colocar o mesmo *view controller* mais de uma vez na pilha. Se for outro objeto, vai te dar dor de cabeça com *leak* de memória, isso se a Apple aceitar o app.

Cada vez que o usuário sai da aplicação e volta, uma nova hierarquia de *controllers* é adicionada em cima da velha, na mesma pilha. Quer testar? Faz esse método ser executado várias vezes e fica olhando o consumo de memória na aba de *debug* do Xcode. Pode parecer bobagem, mas confie em mim, não é. Conforme tua aplicação fica mais complexa, ela vai virar um monstro comedor de memória ram (tipo o google chrome e o firefox), principalmente pra aqueles usuários que ficam alternando de app pra app o tempo inteiro.

Uma solução: reseta a stack inteira chamando o método [popToRootViewControllerAnimated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToRootViewControllerAnimated:). Caso você implemente a **terceira** solução, essa seria uma boa implementação para o método que é chamado quando ocorre a notificação de *application **did** enter foreground*.

Comment: Como posso usar mesmo essa segunda opção que me deu?

Comment: Melhorei a resposta.